# Do comments consume memory and/or use cycles?

Tags: c, node.js, bash, optimization

I am working on several applications for ARM systems using a combination of bash scripting, node.js and C. I use comments when developing to either keep track of what happens in the code or to deactivate actual code.

My experience is that every extra memory pointer and processor cycle slows down the system.

Should I remove all the comments in production code for the sake of optimization or is it not worth worrying about?

Comment: You have three languages.  Which one are you talking about?  What have you tried?  What system/OS are you using?  For 'C', it shouldn't matter unless you include debug info.  For interpreted languages, like Javascript and bash, it will make parsing/loading slightly faster.  You can strip comments as a deployment step so that the *master* source still has comments.

Comment: [Scripting duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372243/optimize-websites-by-removing-code-comments).

Comment: What exactly is your experience? Have you used a profiler?

Comment: This was a question specifically about the ARM processor and not in any way related to websites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other answers mention, there will be no difference in [c](/questions/tagged/c) (or any other compiled) code.

This can be demonstrated as follows:

```
$ touch 0comments.c
$ time gcc -c -o 0comments.o 0comments.c 

real    0m0.022s
user    0m0.009s
sys 0m0.009s
$ seq -f '/* This is comment %g */' 1000000 > 1000000comments.c
$ time gcc -c -o 1000000comments.o 1000000comments.c 

real    0m0.163s
user    0m0.135s
sys 0m0.021s
$ cmp 0comments.o 1000000comments.o
$
```

Two .c files are generated - one empty, and the other with 1000000 comments, then compiled.  The resulting objects are compared, and no differences show up.

Note the compilation time *does* increase, though it is by a pretty insignificant amount per comment, so should not be an issue except in the most extreme circumstances.

---

With [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), I was unable to measure any significant difference with comments in a loop:

```
$ time for i in {0..1000000}; do
> :
> done

real    0m4.054s
user    0m4.006s
sys 0m0.049s
$ time for i in {0..1000000}; do
> :
> # This is a comment
> done

real    0m4.047s
user    0m3.999s
sys 0m0.048s
$
```

...though there may be more rigorous testcases.

Whenever [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) has to parse any kind of loop, it needs to parse the entire loop before executing it (so it knows where to redirect output, etc).  I suspect comments are removed during this parsing, so they don't get reparsed during every loop iteration.

*However*, if comments are not in any kind of loop (or probably function), then the parsing time is small, but measurable:

```
$ seq -f "# This is comment %g" 1000000 > 1000000comments
$ chmod +x 1000000comments 
$ time ./1000000comments 

real    0m1.675s
user    0m1.468s
sys 0m0.207s
$ touch 0comments
$ chmod +x 0comments 
$ time ./0comments 

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.001s
$
```

---

No idea for [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js), though similar to any interpreted language its likely to make little or no difference except in the most extreme of circumstances.

---

The bottom line is - ***please don't remove your comments*** - they are there for a very good reason.  If you remove them, future maintainers of your code (including possibly you) will curse your name forever. ;-)

Comment: I chose this answer as the correct one because I feel that it not only answered the question in depth, but also gave some data. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

It's not necessary to remove comments. When the compiler runs, extra stuff is removed, including comments. Even if you're using an interpreted language, comments don't use CPU cycles because they aren't executable code, although they may add an extremely negligible amount of parsing time.

The point is, **don't worry about it**. You would have to have an absolutely absurd amount of comments to make a reliably measurable difference in compilation or execution time.

Answer (score 2):

In *C* during pre-processing each comment will be replaced by a space character, we can see this by going to [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `5.1.1.2` *Translation phases* paragraph *3* which says:

> [...]Each comment is replaced by one space character. New-line characters are retained. Whether each nonempty sequence of white-space characters other than new-line is retained or replaced by one space character is implementation-defined.

so comments should not make a difference for *C*.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of C, comments are stripped as part of the preprocessing stage and take up no space in the executable; they have exactly zero influence on runtime performance.

Not sure about bash or node.js; I would expect the difference to be negligible to the point of being irrelevant, but the only way to know for sure is to run your own benchmarks, comparing the performance of commented vs. uncommented code.  However, you should only do that if the commented code is failing a hard performance requirement.

**EDIT**

*Please* don't use comments to deactivate code; this practice *will* lead to maintenance headaches down the line (been there, done that, got the t-shirt in multiple sizes and colors).  In the case of C, you can use the preprocessor to control the inclusion of code:

```
#if defined(SOME_MACRO)
/**
 * code that may or may not be active
 */
#endif
```

Otherwise, if code is no longer supposed to be active, **remove it**, and use a version control tool (CVS, git, whatever) to track those changes.